# How to check mailserver supports TLS or Not

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, starttls

I want to check whether mailserver support TLS encryption or not using javamail.

I can able to check via terminal in Linux OS.

```
 >> dig +short gmail.com mx
20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.


>> telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
220 mx.google.com ESMTP c90si10657664pfd.233 - gsmtp
>>ehlo gmail.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, 
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

250 STARTTLS then that email server is configured to support use of TLS.

In the same way, how we can do it using javamail programmatically?

Please help.

Comment: Just try it and see. There's no way to predict the future.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need just "yes, the server supports it" or "no, it does not support it"? Or you have to send an email and want to send it only if you can do it securely?

If it is the former you can just do what telnet does and do not bother using javamail.

If it is the later you can configure javamail to fail if the server does not support TLS. 
See [An SMTP protocol provider for the JavaMail API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) for details. Property 'mail.smtp.starttls.required' is what you need.

Comment: I want to know just the server supports TLS or not. No need to send the mail.

Comment: What will you then do with that information? If the server doesn't support it, what will you do? If the server does support it, what will you do?  Are you never intending to send mail using that server?

Comment: @BillShannon  If the user sends mail to the recipient say x@abc.com. Then I will look incoming smtp server abc.com supports TLS or not in order to show info to user as recipient mail server is not using TLS encryption. Its upto the user to decide whether he need to send or not the information (may be sensitive info.)

Comment: One solution is to turn the problem around. Try to send it securely. If it fails, ask the user if he or she still wants to send the message but not securely.

Comment: The user wants to send mail to x@abc.com, but you're not going to use the abc.com mail server, you're going to use your own mail server.  You're going to tell the sender whether ot not the abc.com mail server supports TLS because the sender might not want to send the message if the recipient's server (abc.com) doesn't support TLS?  No, that won't help at all.  You have no way of knowing whether the recipient's mail reader will **use** TLS when **reading** the message.  TLS support in the smtp server implies nothing about reading the message.

Comment: And all of this ignores the hard problem of finding the server that will actually hold the message, and which might not even be accessible to you.  Messages can be forwarded automatically.  Servers can be hidden behind firewalls.  If you're worried about the security of the message content, you really need to be using something like S/MIME.

Answer (score 0):

how would a java "yes, the server supports it" check for tls look like?

The only way i actual see is to make an dns lookup (e.g. via javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext).

And then connect via telnet (e.g. via apache telnet client)
and parse the

Answer (score 0):

You can query the server with java / jakarta mail using EHLO commands.
The following method queries the server for the support of TLS. No email is send. Other properties could be added. Of course ehlo must be enabled (`mail.smtp.ehlo=true`)

```
boolean detectTls(String smtpServerHost, int smtpServerPort,  String smtpUserName, String smtpUserAccessToken) {
    
    Transport transport = null;
    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpServerPort);
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        //session.setDebug(true);

        transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(smtpServerHost, smtpServerPort, smtpUserName, smtpUserAccessToken);
            
        if(transport instanceof SMTPTransport) {
            return ((SMTPTransport)transport).supportsExtension("STARTTLS");
        }
        return false;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //Proper loggin & exception handling!!!
        //return false;
    }
    finally {
        if(transport!=null) {
            try {
                transport.close();
            }
            catch (MessagingException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```